# Creating single github repository with jenkins for each datastage jobs

Tags: jenkins, github, datastage

I need to create each repository for each job present in the datastage folder.

Previously I was doing this by creating repository one by one for every single job manually..

The problem is I have 1000 jobs in datastage so doing this manually is a time consuming task..

Is there any automation in Jenkins to do the process??

Comment: Whatever structure you have in each repository, can you not simply locate that within a subdirectory within a single repo? A single repo might be messy for 1000 ETL; everyone pulling, merging, pushing - if a lot of activity. Suggest a happy medium, separate into logical groupings (eg: by functional / domain). Also, if the data (not a datastage user) is binary, every commit is a copy, so repos can grow big fast, groupings are better.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mettleci.com](https://www.mettleci.com/mettleci.html) - they've built a whole suite of Continuous DevOps tools around DataStage, including interaction with Jenkins.